# C# System.Windows.Form.Control.MouseClick - Increase clicks per second?

Tags: c#, winforms, mouseevent

I've attached a MouseClick callback function to a System.Windows.Form.Panel. It seems that the click rate is limited to 3~4 mouse clicks per second. How do I remove/increase this limit?

Comment: If you do it too fast then you get MouseDoubleClick.  Use the MouseUp event instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using the MouseDown event instead. I think the MouseClick event has to differentiate between a simple click and the double-click (and therefore might have a delay).